# Create a script with multiple commands to compile a file in OS X

Tags: scripts, feynmf

Suppose I want to compile a file with some Feynman diagrams, using `feynmf` package. To do this, I need to run the following commands:

```
latex file_name.tex
mpost diagram_1.mp
mpost diagram_2.mp
...
mpost diagram_N.mp
latex file_name.tex
dvipdfm file_name.dvi
```

I'd like to create a script that will run all these commands for me, so I don't have to do it by hand. What's the solution to this?

Comment: See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script#Batch_jobs

Comment: Did you try `feynmp-auto`? http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/feynmp-auto/feynmp-auto.pdf

Comment: There are also great tools like e.g. https://github.com/cereda/arara which can help to perform such tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Sigur's link, it's really as simple as a file containing:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# This is somefile.sh
latex file_name.tex
mpost diagram_1.mp
mpost diagram_2.mp
# Any other commands can go here
mpost diagram_N.mp
latex file_name.tex
dvipdfm file_name.dvi
```

and run this once:

```
me@mac:~$ chmod 755 somefile.sh
```

and this as often as needed:

```
me@mac:~$ ./somefile.sh
```

If I wanted to get fancier, I could do:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# This is somefile.sh
TEXFILE=file_name
MPFILES=`ls *.mp`
latex ${TEXFILE}
for MP in ${MPFILES}; do
  mpost ${MP}
done
latex ${TEXFILE}
dvipdfm ${TEXFILE}
```

Comment: The non-fancier code works perfectly! The fancier one gets stuck on doing Metapost commands:

Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.005) ) (./feynmp.mp)

Here feynmp.mp is the file one needs to put in the same folder as the tex file to compile Feynman diagrams. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Never used feynmp, but I assume it's not on the list of things you'd run mpost on. If so, adjust the `ls` command to list the .mp files you want to use.